# Exception with sending mails "address in mailbox given does not comply with rfc 2822 swift"

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I got this exception while trying to use symfony spool mailer any ideas why I can't catch it?

**address in mailbox given does not comply with rfc 2822 swift**

```
try
{
$mailer->send($message);
}
catch (Swift_RfcComplianceException $e)
{
echo "!! Invalid email address : ".$e->getMessage()."\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Symfony cant cache any Exception with below:

```
            try {
                ..
            } catch (Exception $exc) {
                ...
            }
```

because of if you didn't specified Exception as Exception in a use statement. (PHP tries to find \YourNamespaceWithController\Exception instead of \Exception.) so you can use

```
            try {
                ..
            } catch (\Exception $exc) {
                ...
            }
```

in your case you can use specified exception as

```
            try {
                ..
            } catch (\Swift_RfcComplianceException $exc) {
                ...
            }
```